# Why don't CDNs require authentication to access static files?

Tags: authentication, facebook

Why don't companies like Facebook require authenticated HTTP/HTTPS requests to access content (like images) using CDNs?

In a way, once one "friend" can access the image URL, he/she can effectively publish that URL to the world, allowing anonymous access. This is literally "security through obscurity", as it only relies on the URL consisting of a (UUID-like) fbID being secret. I believe Facebook calls this a Capability-based security model, but wouldn't it make sense to tie URLs to particular users to have attribution, as well as employ some form of periodic URL/fbID rotation?

Comment: That "friend" could also save your image, put it on their own website, and publish that to the world.

Comment: Tie the URL to the viewer? Then the viewer could do exactly what I just said and still not be traced. Now, maybe you're asking "Why not watermark every image on a social network to identify leaks?" That is potentially interesting - but it is not what you asked, and it is sufficiently different that you should ask a new question rather than edit this one.

Comment: @paj28 I refer to the last part of the question-- `but wouldn't it make sense to tie URLs to particular users to have attribution`. e.g. make the fbID incorporate the viewer's user ID.

Comment: I refer to the first part of the comment - Tie the URL to the viewer? Then the viewer could do exactly what I just said and still not be traced.

Comment: Yes, an evil "friend" could download the content, then upload it to its own server and publish this. But doing this is a much more criminal action than just sharing the URL. If you are able the share a URL which servers the data without auth, then a fraud can happen without knowing it easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this is large scale applications. When you have large scale applications, checking for authorization takes unacceptable amount of resources. Thats why static resources, like pictures, videos and other content, are stored externally on static CDN servers using a random token, and then the authorized response can include this token.

This means they only need a few replicated database servers, and then they can have large amounts of CDN servers that cache each other permanently.

Distributed servers is what makes rotation difficult aswell, as then the static CDN servers need to be told to rotate that value. And that incurs unacceptable resource usage, as that needs to be done periodically. As opposed to a random value only needs to be set at upload.

Even calculating a md5 hash, generating a random value or something that seems "simple", can be a heavy lift for a distributed CDN server to do.

So the server is a simple storage of files. Basically, all authentication and generating of random values happen on the "active servers" (that run code), while the static servers only store files based on filenames, and serves files based on filenames.

Comment: Making one part of the file identifier tie into to the user who is viewing it may cost a little more in terms of storage and lookup time, but at least ties the user to the content. Is that still infeasible?

Comment: Yes, because then you would need to store the picture once for each user that wants to see the picture. Remember that the CDNs basically don't execute code, they just serve static content directly from a drive. See it as a internet connected harddrive.

Comment: Right, and think of this as symlinks...

Comment: Yeah, symbolic links would work, but the caching servers would still receive the full content when the caching servers gets a request for a picture that is not part of their cache. And then you should rewrite all the caching servers to tell the other caching servers wherever to request a softlink or when to to request the full content. What if the caching server don't have the base content? It quickly becomes the largest mess in the world, considering the amount of users Facebook have.

Answer (score 2):

Some CDNs today do offer some form of the capability you're describing. For example, Azure allows for [token authentication on some of their CDNs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth)

> Token authentication is a mechanism that allows you to prevent the Azure Content Delivery Network (CDN) from serving assets to unauthorized clients

Like the other answer stated, these mechanisms can have a severe impact on scalability and latency, hence why they are very restricted.